# How to insert a data to mysql by python

Tags: php, python, mysql

- I have table with 3 column: ID; TIMEON; TIMEOFF; TIMEUSE.
- with data
  22 | 2016-05-25 19:17:11 | 2016-05-26 18:26:43 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00

  > #!/usr/bin/env python
  >
  > ```
  > import time
  > import MySQLdb
  > import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
  > import datetime
  > from datetime import datetime
  > from time import localtime, strftime, strptime
  >
  > db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="123", passwd="tesst", db="raspi")
  > cur= db.cursor()
  > cur.execute("SELECT TIMEON, TIMEOFF FROM DP WHERE Id = 22")
  > time_results = cur.fetchall()
  >
  > for row in time_results:
  >     tgianON = row[0]
  >     tgianOFF = row[1]
  >
  > aaa = abs(tgianOFF - tgianON)
  >
  > print aaa
  >
  > cur.execute("UPDATE DP SET TIMEUSE=%s WHERE Id = %s",(aaa, 22))
  > db.commit()
  > cur.close()
  > db.close()
  > ```
- I want to caculate time between TIMEON and TIMEOFF then insert it to mysql in current row (TIMEUSE in my table) but run it error:
- It can print the time but can't insert data

  ```
  22:46:54
    tet.py:17: Warning: Out of range value for column 'TIMEUSE' at row 1
  ```

  cur.execute("UPDATE DP SET TIMEUSE=%s WHERE Id = %s",(aaa, 22))

Comment: everybody help me !!!!

Comment: Can you please share the desc of table?
That is desc DP;